# Parse Stackdriver LogEntry JSON in Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm building a Dataflow pipeline to process Stackdriver logs, the data are read from Pub/Sub and results written into BigQuery.
When I read from Pub/Sub I get JSON strings of [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) objects but what I'm really interested in is `protoPayload.line` records which contain user log messages. To get those I need to parse `LogEntry` JSON object and I found a two years old [Google example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/processing-logs-using-dataflow/blob/87ee53d149f72a437eee91999ff0f615ec25ebfa/dataflow/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/solutions/LogAnalyticsPipeline.java#L83) how to do it:

```java
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.logging.model.LogEntry;

try {
    JsonParser parser = new JacksonFactory().createJsonParser(entry);
    LogEntry logEntry = parser.parse(LogEntry.class);
    logString = logEntry.getTextPayload();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("IOException parsing entry: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {
    LOG.error("NullPointerException parsing entry: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, the `logEntry.getTextPayload()` returns `null`. I'm not even sure if it's suppose to work as `com.google.api.services.logging` library is not mentioned anywhere in Google Cloud docs, the current logging library seems to be [google-cloud-logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

So if anyone could suggest what is the right or simplest way of parsing `LogEntry` objects?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with manually parsing `LogEntry` JSON with gson library, using the tree traversing approach in particular.
Here is a small snippet:

```js
static class ProcessLogMessages extends DoFn<String, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String entry = c.element();

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(entry);
        if (element.isJsonNull()) {
            return;
        }
        JsonObject root = element.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray lines = root.get("protoPayload").getAsJsonObject().get("line").getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject line = lines.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            String logMessage = line.get("logMessage").getAsString();

            // Do what you need with the logMessage here
            c.output(logMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

This is simple enough and works fine for me since I'm interested in `protoPayload.line.logMessage` objects only. But I guess this is not ideal way of parsing `LogEntry` objects if you need to work with many attributes.